# How to access contents of pure ES6 modules (no Webpack) in Chrome console

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

Context:

Direct output from `tsc` targeting `es6` for the language and modules.

Scripts load and work correctly once served from a server. But I don't see how one can access variables in modules through the console. The file names aren't available as objects (somehow) representing the modules so I can access them through that, and I can't import anything in the console.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there's an official way to do this; if not, I would definitely suggest [filing a bug](https://www.chromium.org/for-testers/bug-reporting-guidelines) if there isn't one already.

I can offer a workaround: add a line of code to one of the modules to assign the variable you want to access to a property of the window.  For example, for the "live demo" linked from [this article](https://jakearchibald.com/2017/es-modules-in-browsers/), you could just add `window.addTextToBody = addTextToBody` to the main module embedded in the HTML.  If you don't want to actually modify the module, there's always the trick of adding a conditional breakpoint that executes the desired code in the target scope and always returns false, e.g., a breakpoint with a condition of `window.addTextToBody = addTextToBody; false`.